# "call to OpenGL ES API with no current context" while using imageloader in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, thread-safety, universal-image-loader

i am getting message:

**call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)**

and my app runs fine but nothing appears in view pager .I have used imageloader to download images and display them in it.

i think i have used imageloader incorrectly

my pageradapter class:

```
 public class pageradapter extends PagerAdapter {


    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    List<String> l = MainActivity.list;
    ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    public pageradapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        //  View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.img, container, false);
          ImageLoader mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

mLayoutInflater=((LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.img, container, false);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);



        mImageLoader.displayImage(l.get(position),imageView);


        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Comment: It means you're calling an OpenGL ES function without an OpenGL ES context. The code you've provided does not have any OpenGL ES functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning message and searched a lot over internet but found no solution. Somewhere I read about setting viewpager's fragment's imageview layout_width and layout_height to match_parent and it works. Don't know how. I used FragmentPagerAdapter and was downloading and displaying images over internet.